# Include a partial template

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to use Drupal 8, with a custom theme, due big structure differences for my requirements I have a page--front.twig.html and a page.twig.html, I would like to create template parts as used in phrozn oder in a normal Symfony2 project, for example a footer.html.twig and a header.html.twig. These templates are saved under a subdirectory /parts/.

But when I call this templates as normal I just receive a string with the name of the template.

For example:

```
{# in page.html.twig or page--front.html.twig #}
{% include 'parts/footer.html.twig' %}
```

Returns the file name as string:

```
parts/footer.html.twig
```

It's possible to do that with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't do relative paths, all paths must either be from the Drupal root or based on the namespaced path to your 'templates' directory: https://www.drupal.org/node/2143557.

I would avoid "from the Drupal root" and use namespaces, at least until https://www.drupal.org/node/2291449 is resolved.

```
{% include '@mytheme/parts/footer.html.twig' %}
```

> Edit: If you want to pass additional arguments for loop or for
>   checking some vars to your included `twig` template you should write
>   in this way:

```
{% include '@mytheme/includes/form-block.html.twig' with {dog: true} %}
```

Edit: Now that https://www.drupal.org/node/2291449 has been committed you can also do:

```
{% include 'footer.html.twig' %}
```

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2369981 for why you saw the file name as a string instead of a helpful exception.

Comment: What about `include` and passing values? Suppose I would like to include `image-formatter` and passing the `url` null to avoid making linked image.

Comment: The examples provided in this answer do not seem to work.

Comment: Be aware that `@mytheme` resolves to the path of `mytheme` + the string `/templates`. In other words, `@mytheme` resolves to the `mytheme/templates` directory.

Comment: To further clarify the comment from @daniels. If your custom theme is named **mytheme** and it is located at **'themes/custom/mytheme'** then the Twig namespace `@mytheme` resolves to **'themes/custom/mytheme/templates'**. Including a template located at `@mytheme/fragments/footer.html.twig` means it will resolve to **'themes/custom/mytheme/templates/fragments/footer.html.twig'**

Answer (score 22):

Use a full path to the theme directory. If you use the namespace you'll have to change it if you bring the code to another site or theme.

This should work:

```
{% include directory ~ '/templates/parts/footer.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: this is very handy when doing sub-themeing.  Set this in your Parent theme, and then have a version in the child theme's template directory.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: Note:  `directory` does unexpected things if you're building a parent theme that is intended to be extended and overridden with subthemes.See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3049414

Answer (score 7):

Note you can pass variables after the `with` keyword :

```
{# template.html will have access to the variables from the current context and the additional ones provided #}
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}

{% set vars = {'foo': 'bar'} %}
{% include 'template.html' with vars %}
```

See Twig documentation http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Answer (score 5):

It's also possible to use Twig's use of an array to create a fallback when the file doesn't exist.

Eg. If footer.html.twig isn't available, defaultfooter.html.twig would be used.

```
{{ include([
  '@yourthemename/parts/footer.html.twig',
  '@yourthemename/parts/defaultfooter.html.twig'
]) }}
```

Combine this with the use of variables in the filenames and you can include different files depending on some sort of context.

Nb: I'm still trying to work out whether this is best practice or not.

Answer (score 5):

Now that [Add Twig template inheritance based on the theme registry, enable adding Twig loaders](https://www.drupal.org/node/2291449) has been committed, you can also use the following line.

```
{% include 'footer.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 8

**Including a twig file in the theme**
when you do an `{% include 'FILE_NAME.html.twig' %}` Drupal expects that you FILE will be located in your current Theme Directory.
Just put it there and it's going to work.

**Including a twig file in your Module**

If you want to add it in a MODULE, you have to declare it in the THEME Function.
In your .module file just add the following:

```
<?php function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {   
   'FILE_NAME' => [
      'variables' => [
      ],
      'template' => 'FILE_NAME',
    ], ?>
```

Then put your Twig file in YOUR_MODULE/template/FILE_NAME.html.twig

Comment: It is wrong information about path. To include file from module with theme hook, you need another way:

{{ include('@yourModuleName/twigFileName.html.twig', { var1: var1Val, var2: var2Val }) }}

Don't forget, that templates files must be in 'yourModuleName/templates/'.