# Include a part template on specific node page

Tags: theming, 8

I would like to include some custom html code only on a specific node.
I created "parts" directory and put a custom twig template in it. (mytheme/templates/parts/custom_html.html.twig)

I then copied over the page.html.twig to my templates directory, and included the custom template with:

```
{% include directory ~ '/templates/parts/custom_html.html.twig' %}
```

I want to show this only on a certain node, say "node/2". I don't wan't to create a custom template just for this page, like "page--node--2.html.twig".

Is there a way of using a condition to just show this template on the specific node?

Kind of like this?

```
{% if 'node/2' %}
    {% include directory ~ '/templates/parts/custom_html.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This answer is a couple of years old, but it may help http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/141104/42650

Comment: Thanks, but that post doesn't explain how to do the "if" statement. I'm adding the include in the main "page.html.twig" because I don't want to create a whole new node-specific template for just this one include.

Answer (score 1):

If you want override page.html.twig for special node 2. You can try this code

```
{% if node.id == '2' %}
   {% include directory ~ '/templates/parts/custom_html.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

if other template you need process in your function theme first:

```
YOUR_THEME_process_FUNCTION_THEME(&$vars) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $vars['node'] = $node;
  }
}
```